# how to make a proxy for cross domain ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

How do I send a cross-domain XMLhttp request via JavaScript, where i am using javascript on the client side and jsp on the server side.

here is the ajax code used in the javascript file given below:

```js
function onWrite(comment)
   { var xmlhttp;
var url="http://10.155.125.219/manga/MapWrite";
  alert("HI"+comment);   
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  alert("Megha");
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
  {
  alert("request successful");
  document.getElementById("infotxt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  alert("Hi"+xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","url",true);
  xmlhttp.send(); 
   }
```

and on the server side my jsp page looks like:

```jsp
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<% 

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bi_police";      
        try 
        {

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        } 
        catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try
        {
        Connection con;
        ResultSet rs;
        PreparedStatement ps;

        String sqlstr = "SELECT * from case_fact ";

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"postgres","postgres");
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlstr);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
            out.println(rs.getString(2));
            }       
            con.close(); 
        } 
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
        } %>
```

now according to me i am unable to access data from different domain due to which i am unable to access the data from the server.
so plzz anyone can recommend anything and plzz if you want to suggest something write it in the form of code.